# PHP Function to search values in database and replace in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, replace

I am building a web scraper in PHP and I am not so experimented with all this stuff. What I am trying to achieve is as following:

- Split an array of values into strings using foreach
- Search any value in a predefined MYSQL table. If value is identical with one of the defined ones, it should be replaced. Otherwise it should remain the same
- Put the new values back into an array

Below is my snippet. Basic structure of database is "`ID`, `Marime`, `Inlocuire`". "`Marime`" is the column to search on, and "`Inlocuire`" is the column to replace value with.

```
foreach ($marimi as $marime) {
        $sizes[]=trim(strtok($marime->innertext, '-'));
        $newArray = array_filter($sizes, 'myFilter');

        foreach ($newArray as $marimeFixa) {
            $marimeDefinita = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM oc_1_tabelmarimi WHERE Marime = '$marimeFixa'");
            if($marimeDefinita->num_rows == 0) {
                $marimeFixa = $marimeFixa;
            } else {
                $marimeFixa = $marimeDefinita['Inlocuire'];
            }
            $arrayMarimi[] = $marimeFixa;
        }
        print_r($arrayMarimi);
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What seems to be not working ? Please add details about the issues you are facing.

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Select Size
)

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /home/ob2011/public_html/stockscan.php:59`

Comment: Do `var_dump` of `$marimeDefinita` and check its structure. It seems to be an object, while you are using it as an array.

Comment: This returns me `bool(false)`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$marimeDefinita = $marimeDefinita->fetch_assoc();
```

before `if($marimeDefinita->num_rows == 0) {`

or

```
$marimeFixa = $marimeDefinita->Inlocuire;
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /home/ob2011/public_html/stockscan.php:57`

Comment: First answer from you seem to be working, however none of the values get replaced.

Comment: It looks like the query is recognized as boolean for some reason